# How to limit the input to double?

Tags: php

Is there any way to limit the user to enter double data type input? I found something like number_format and round but it can't pass thru the `preg_match` when the input include `.`

I wanted a error message to pop up when the user type in string so I put the `preg_match`.

In my database, the data type for this input is `double`.

My code

```
$volume = $_POST['volume'];
$roundUp = number_format((float)$volume, 2, '.', '');

if(empty($volume)){
    $errorMsg['emptyVolume'] = "Volume cannot be blank!";
}
elseif (!preg_match('/^\d+$/',$volume)) {
    $errorMsg['pregVolume'] = "Volume can only be integer!";
}
```

Comment: You can use [floatval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) . It converts a variable to float/double. If the variable does not start with number it will return 0.

Comment: @Slavian unless it starts with `.` ;)